# copy and insert an exisiting row at next position in datatable c#

Tags: c#, datatable, copy

I have a dataTable and need to copy a line x times (named by xMulti) bellow the original.
How i can do this?
My example gives a error.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YCasW.png)

```
int xMultiPos = 0;
if (DtTbl.Columns.Contains("xMulti"))
{
    xMultiPos = DtTbl.Columns.IndexOf("xMulti"); // set the position of the multiplikator
    foreach (DataRow row in DtTbl.Rows)
    {
        int xMultiplicatorTemp = int.Parse((string)row[xMultiPos]); // convert the multiplicator to an int value
        if (xMultiplicatorTemp > 1)
        {
            TB_Info.Text = "vorhanden";
            for (int i = 0; i < xMultiplicatorTemp; i++)
            {
                int index = DtTbl.Rows.IndexOf(row);
                try
                {
                    DataRow temp = (DataRow)row[index]; // this will not work, because it is text?
                    DtTbl.Rows.InsertAt(temp, index);
                }
                catch (Exception msg)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine(msg);
                    throw;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8o2kN.png)

Comment: It is very difficult to understand what you are asking. The picture looks like an Excel file and the code looks like it is using a `DataTable`? On the first `if` statement… `if (DtTbl.Columns.Contains("xMulti")) …` … ? the picture shows two (2) columns named “xMulti”? Again the picture does not match the code. Can you clarify any of this? The rest of the code is a mystery as to what you are trying to do. However, to help, there are a couple of things the code is doing that ARE going to cause problems.

Comment: 1) The code has a `foreach` loop… `foreach (DataRow row in DtTbl.Rows)…` … This is looping through the `DataTable` `DtTbl.Rows` “collection.” This is fine, however, later in the code there is the line of code… `DtTbl.Rows.InsertAt(temp, index);` … ? … This MAY work, however, it is usually a bad idea to “alter” the “collection” WHILE the “collection” is being used in a `for` loop or `foreach` loop. Inserting a row into the `DtTbl`’s rows collection inside a loop through that collection is risky.

Comment: 2) Another issue you MAY come across is that when the line of code… `DataRow temp = (DataRow)row[index];` executes, it will set `temp` to the `DataRow` at `index` from the `DataTable` `DtTbl`. This is fine, However, on the next line to “insert” the row, you may have a problem there and an error complaining something like… _”cannot add ‘existing’ row to collection”… this basically means that the row is ALREADY in the collection. Even if you had a “different” table that you wanted to insert into, then, the error will complain that the same row cannot belong to two (2) tables.

Comment: Lastly, one possible option is to create a new `DataTable` and use the [DataTable.ImportRow(DataRow) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.importrow?view=net-5.0) … to “import” the rows you want from the other tables into your new table. This will solve both issues previously described.

Comment: Hi JohnG
Many thanks for your help. I use your last option. DataTable.ImportRow(DataRow) Method …
I fixed it so and it works fine :-)